# if such$\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{47}<\dfrac{n}{m}<\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{43}$ Find this $m$ minimum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $m,n\in N^{+}$, if such

$$\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{47}<\dfrac{n}{m}<\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{43}$$
Find the $m$ minimum the value

My try: since 
$$(\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{47})m<n<(\sqrt{43}+\sqrt{41})m$$
then
$$\dfrac{10m}{\sqrt{47}-\sqrt{37}}<n<\dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{43}-\sqrt{41}}$$

(maybe this problem use pell equation?)

then I can't,Thank you very much

Comment: your inequality is impossible since $\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{47}<\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{43}$

Comment: I have edit..(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since

$$\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{47}=12.9384....$$
$$\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{43}=12.9605....$$

Write

$$\frac{n}{m}=13-\frac{k}{m}$$ Then

$$13-0.0616< 13-\frac{k}{m}< 13-0.039$$
Hence
$$.0616 > \frac{k}{m} \geq \frac{1}{m}$$

This proves that

$$m \geq \frac{1}{0.0616}=16.23$$

Thus, $m \geq 17$.

For $17$ it is easy to show that $13-\frac{1}{17}$ has the desired property.

**P.S.** If $m > \frac{1}{b-a}$ then it is trivial to prove that there exists an $n$ so that $a\leq \frac{n}{m} <b$. This simple result, shows that any $m \geq 45$ works, and reduces the problem to a finite computation: check which $1 \leq m \leq 44$ works...

**Edit** Fixed some mistakes in the computations...

Comment: Hello,You mean $m=17$ is minimum?

Comment: I am probably missing something. How does this ensure that $n$ is an integer?

Comment: @user17762 $13-\frac{1}{17}=\frac{13\cdot 17-1}{17}$ So $n=13 \cdot 17-1$ which is an integer.

Comment: @chinamath I proved that $m \geq 17$. And for $m=17$ setting $n=13 \cdot 17-1=220$ works.

Comment: A different way to show that $17$ is minimal is to compute the continued fraction expansion (of both numbers). If 16 were possible, then $207/16% would be the magic number, but it is bigger than the RHS.

Comment: To elaborate on the above, $207/16$ is one of the convergents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{37} + \sqrt{47}$ and it is _larger_ that $\sqrt{41} + \sqrt{43}.$ Since we know that no fraction with denominator at most $16$ is closer to $\sqrt{37} + \sqrt{47},$ all such fractions are either smaller than $\sqrt{37} + \sqrt{47}$ or bigger than $207/16,$ and hence than $\sqrt{41} + \sqrt{43}.$

Comment: @IgorRivin $207/16  = (160+48-1)/16 = 13-1/16 < \sqrt{37} + \sqrt{47} < 13-1/17$, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

This provides only a partial answer. What you have gives us
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{43}-\sqrt{41}}2n < m < \dfrac{\sqrt{47}-\sqrt{37}}{10}n$$
Hence, a sufficient condition is that if we ensure that $\dfrac{\sqrt{47}-\sqrt{37}}{10}n -\dfrac{\sqrt{43}-\sqrt{41}}2n > 1$, there is definitely an integer $m$. Hence, $n \geq 7573$. Choosing $n=7573$, gives $m=585$. However, this does not ensure that $m$ is a minimum. All we can say is that the $m$ we are after is $\leq 585$.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is find this $m$ minimum,$m=585$ maynot minimum?

Comment: @chinamath Yes. Finding the minimum requires some more thought.